# Push Cloud Foundry App Without Overriding Certain Files

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Is there a way to push a Cloud Foundry application without overriding certain files?

For example, I have a Django app but I don't want the sqlite DB to be overwritten each time I push my new code.  I tried using `.cfignore` but that removes the files from Bluemix resulting in errors in the application.  I'm using the latest version of the IBM Cloud CLI to push the code and here is the command I'm using:

`ibmcloud cf push APP_NAME`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#filesystem

You could possibly use `scp` to update your local sqlite file to match what's in your deployed app, though: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#other-ssh-access